# Insert character at a specific place in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, insert, jupyter-notebook

I have the following issue. I would like to insert "," after each ")" in the following string from a specific Column.

```
The Bahamas (All locations)Bermuda (All locatins)Romania (Cluj)Bulgaria (All locations)
```

The idea is that I have this type of string on multiple lines of the same column, of the same table. Please Help me on this issue.

I expecting to have:

```
The Bahamas (All locations),Bermuda (All locatins),Romania (Cluj),Bulgaria (All locations),
```

In order to split in the way I need the information.

Comment: In [1]: df['column']=df['column'].str.replace(')','),')

I resolved the question after some meticulous search

Answer (score 4):

Use str.replace():

```
In [1]: s1 = 'The Bahamas (All locations)Bermuda (All locatins)Romania (Cluj)Bulgaria (All locations)'

In [2]: s2 = s1.replace(')', '),')

In [3]: s2
Out[3]: 'The Bahamas (All locations),Bermuda (All locatins),Romania (Cluj),Bulgaria (All locations),'
```

Comment: Faroe Islands (All locations)Guernsey (All locations)
Albania (All locations)Andorra (All locations)
Åland Islands (All locations)Bulgaria (All locations)

This is how my column looks like (column name = Country)
Please tell me how can I use, instead of writing s1 = String -> s1 = Column name and then make all this work for the column

Comment: Do you mean pandas column? Pandas not in tags, so I didn't get it. For pandas use https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html